# Customer Permission to certain sites

Tags: customer-account, permissions

I would like to know if it possible to give certain customers privileges, that not all customers can get. For example Customers A and B may access this part of the website, by following a link. But Customer C gets a message, stating that he does not have these privileges. I thought maybe through giving certain users different 'user-groups' or so.

Is this possible with Magento?

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension to hide some categories from customer groups. 
https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2